# how to get the tcp header of a received packet in socket programming?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, raw-sockets

I want to get the TCP header of each received TCP packet (destined for a specific program,namely, a port)
it seems not possible to use recv() or recvfrom() to get the TCP header using regular socket.

So, I want to use raw socket
with raw socket, I can use recvfrom() to receive all IP packets destined to the host
if the host receives a lot packets, 
I need to check the port number of each packet so see whether it is the needed.
then it could be very time and CPU comsuming?

```
while（）
{
recvfrom();
check_port_number(); 
}
```

are there any good ways to get the tcp header of a received tcp packet?
I'm working with linux c, so THE solution should be linux c-based. thanks!

Comment: For what purpose? There are APIs to get most of it field by field.

Comment: I just want to get the TCP header of all tcp packets that are destined to a specific port number on the destination machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap.3pcap.html) API, not the socket API. libpcap lets you read packets right off the wire.

Another library you can use to ease parsing the packets is libnet.

Comment: are there any good articles or examples which are very directly related to what I need? thanks!

Comment: how about DPI? is it OK or not?