# how to modify packet header(IP header, TCP Header) before the host send them into the network

Tags: c, network-programming, linux-kernel

I want to modify packet header(IP header, TCP Header) before the host send them into the network.

For example, if I'm using firefox for browsing, then I want to intercept all the packets from firefox and modify the IP/TCP header and then send them into the network.

so basically, there are two requirements:
1 intercept all the packets from firefox(but not other programs). if this is not possible, is it possible to intercept the packets from a specific port or ip/port pair

2 modify the IP/TCP header and then inject them into the network

are there ways, APIs to achieve this?
how about libpcap?
are there similar source code snippets?
I'm working with linux c

thanks!

Comment: It seems you want [deep packet inspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection).

Comment: are there any code examples that are close to my requirements? thanks!

Comment: I am still wondering what both this question and [your other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422041/how-to-get-the-tcp-header-of-a-received-packet-in-socket-programming) are actually about. What in the TCP header do you need to see and change, that can't be accomplished via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razorback is an open source API for deep packet injection.
You can find the source at:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/razorbacktm/files/Razorback/

You can also request them for the source code for their proposed system.

http://www.icir.org/vern/papers/pktd-pam03.pdf

Answer (score 4):

To modify the packets, it is better as simple as injecting the packet which is modified into your network.
C has a library libnet which does every thing related to packet injection.
Python has scapy to inject the packets .

Now you can do quite interesting things , with libent and scapy , instead of modifying your packet ip/tcp headers , perform arp spoofing and then inject falsify packets and redirect them to the victim.

Libpcap is used for capturing packets but not for modifying packets . So you can build your own sniffer using libpcap , but to inject/modify packets you need to use libnet .

To make life simpler , there are tools like burp suite etc..where you can modify the http headers only before forwarding it .

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for this question. In fact `libnet` is fit for the purpose and is decently maintained

Comment: Hey if you really want to explore the power of python , you could actually use a third party  library called netfilterqueue along with scapy , capture the packets in queue , modify it by using scapy and inject back using set payload function in netfilterqueue

Answer (score -3):

it should be for you [Network packet capturing for Linux](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-packet/section5.html).

But it seems to intercept all process in the system.

---

maybe you can use

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
long ptrace (enum __ptrace_request request,
             pid_t pid,
             void *addr,
             void *data);
```

and hook send(2) or recv(2) to modify the tcp header.

Comment: capturing is not enough, because the original packets are still sent out to the network. I need to intercep them