# sent packet is different from received packet

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

I use raw socket to create TCP packets, with focus on the sequence number and TCP flags(SYN, ACK)

I used one machine S to send a tcp ACK packet (flag ACK is set to 1) and another machine R to receive it these two machines are in different subnets, all in my school

meanwhile, I used tcpdump to capture the packets.

Strange things happens! On machine S, the captured packet is as expected, it is an ACK packet however, on the receiving machine R, the packet becomes a SYN packet, and the sequence number is changed, the seq no is 1 smaller the expected and the ack_seq become 0!

what are potential problems?
my guess is that the router/firewall modified the ACK packet to a SYN packet because it never sees a SYN SYN/ACK exchange ahead of the ACK?
is it possible or not?

the two captured packets are:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09y_TWqTtwlVnpuUlNwUmM1YUE/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09y_TWqTtwlTXhjUms4ZnlkMVE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you will encounter will be that the receiving TCP stack in each case will receive the packet and possibly reply to it. What you are attempting is really not possible.

Comment: I don't care the consequence at the moment, I just hope the receving host can receive the packet correctly!

Comment: It's not very likely. You still haven't answer the question as to [what this is all about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428694/how-to-modify-packet-headerip-header-tcp-header-before-the-host-send-them-int).