# is it possible to get the TCP sequence number of SYN/ACK packet in TCP 3-way handshaking?

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming

I have a tcp client program
when it initiates a 3-way handshaking with a remote tcp server by sending a SYN
it will receive a SYN/ACK from the server,

is it possible to read the sequence number and acknowledgement sequence number of the SYN/ACK packet?
if so ,how to do it?
BTW, I'm working on linux c
thanks!

Comment: What are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: He's been asked that [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428694/how-to-modify-packet-headerip-header-tcp-header-before-the-host-send-them-int), more than once. No response whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible but it's not easy as traditional socket programming. Which hides handshake stage from you.

You should use something like [pcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.htm) to capture what you need.
Or, [Raw sockets](http://frankjennings.sys-con.com/node/34589/mobile).

Answer (score 1):

Use a Raw TCP socket. There is a IPPROTO_TCP protocol option in creating raw sockets. With that, the data is everything embedded in the link layer headers, so you will see the IP Header, followed by the TCP Header, followed by the payload data for each packet received. You need to parser the sequence from it.

Reference to [TCP Header Formatter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out TCP sequence or ACK numbers by using **tcpdump** in linux or **wireshark**. Afterwards, just analyze the packets and you can figure it out.

However to build your own program to find out TCP sequence or ACK number, then you need to use the **pcap** library in C to capture all the packets and then write your code to sniff only TCP sequence and ACK numbers within the packets.

You can set your own TCP sequence and ACK numbers, provided you build your own packets. You can use **Libnet** to do it, construct your own packet or use **RAW sockets**.

If you are not familiar with **pcap** library, then you could write a simple bash script which redirects the all packet captured data into a file and then use AWK / SED filtering techniques to find out the TCP sequence and ACK numbers.