# How to receive tcp flags in a socket connection

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I've created a socket connection in c between my Raspberry Pi and another device where the Pi is the client.

Is there anyway to handle TCP flags in the packets received from the server?

In particular, I want certain code to execute if the response has a FIN flag.

Comment: Are you running Linux on your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the tcp header of a received packet in socket programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422041/how-to-get-the-tcp-header-of-a-received-packet-in-socket-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to observe TCP flags to detect FIN. `recv` will return 0. If you want to try to observe whether or not `recv` would return 0 without disturbing the buffered data on the socket, you can use [`MSG_PEEK`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17705579/315052), and if you need it to be non-blocking, you can combine it with [`MSG_DONTWAIT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24639654/315052).